# target_id always null

Tags: facebook-fql

I'm developing an app to show the user news feeds, everything is fine, except for the "target_id" var, it's returning always a null value.

When I test the first query on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/ and add the "target_id" var to the query, It return the values correctly, but when I run the same query with an access_token of my app, always return null for "target_id"

I suspect this may be a problem with the permission, but I added all the permissions to my app and the problem persists. Any help whith this?. Thanks